# How does MS teams incoming webhook work without a web socket?

Tags: javascript, webhooks

How does MS teams receives an incoming webhook triggered from an external application? I couldn't find any setInterval api calls.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have a fundamental misunderstanding of what a webhook is.  It doesn't have anything to do with websockets or `setInterval`, it's just an HTTP endpoint that an external service can send a JSON message to that is processed by teams and results in a message being posted to the appropriate teams channel.
Displaying that message is the only part of that process that happens on the client where you could potentially be able to see the code involved.

Comment: The http endpoint will be handled by the teams. How teams send it to the client?

Comment: The client is connected to the server with websockets, so when the server receives a webhook over HTTP, it then resends it to all the currently connected clients over websockets

Comment: couldn't find a WS instance in the browser when using teams.